# Using named pipes to create a 'loop'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I'm very new to shell scripting and I am trying to get to grips with piping. I could be heading in completely the wrong direction here...

What I have is a shell script that contains a simple while true loop, within this loop I am getting netcat to listen on a specified port and piping input to a binary file that is awaiting for commands through stdin. This is Script-A

I have a second shell script that accepts input as arguments, it then echos those arguments to the port that netcat is listening on. This is Script-B

My aim is to get the returning output from the binary file located in Script-A into Script-B via Netcat so that it can be returned via stdout. The binary file has to be initialized and awaiting input.

This is what I have:

Script-A

```
while true; do
    nc -kl 1234 | /binarylocation/ --readargumentsfromstdinflag
done
```

Script-B

```
foo=$(echo "$*" | nc localhost 1234)
echo "$foo"
```

With this setup, the output of the binary file is done via Script-A
After doing some research I got to this point, I am trying to use a named pipe to create a sort of loop from the binary file back to netcat, it's still not working -

Script-A

```
mkfifo foobar

while true; do
    nc -kl 1234 < foobar | /binarylocation/ --readargumentsfromstdinflag > foobar
done
```

Script-B hasn't changed.

Bear in mind my shell scripting experience stems over a period of about a single day, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your script B.. netcat reads from STDIN and exits immediately when STDIN is closed, not waiting for the response.

you will realize when you do this:

```
foo=$( ( echo -e "$*"; sleep 2 ) | nc localhost 1234) 
echo "$foo"
```

`nc` has a parameter for the stdin behaviour..

```
 -q    after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and 
       then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever.`
```

So you should do:

```
foo=$( echo -e "$*" | nc -q5 localhost 1234) 
echo "$foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s), I cant get back to testing for a few days. I have not forgot about this question - don't worry!

Comment: worked perfectly :-) Thanks for your patience and persistence!