# Pipe looping in shell script

Tags: shell, powershell

I am curious about the possibility to form loops in shell pipes. I use Windows Power Shell specifically. If I had a game AI, like GNU Go, is it possible to link two copies of them together and have them play one another? A pipe loop is my idea.

I see a couple of limitations. A) the program would have to output the same commands as the user would usually give for input, so that the second instance would understand the first and vice-versa. This makes almost all CLI games unsuitable because of their text-based visual feedback. B) there would need to be a Tee to inspect the pipe as the game is played, which may be slightly difficult to use. I have also read [using named pipes to create a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376830/using-named-pipes-to-create-a-loop) and seen the problems with keeping the pipe open.

What options are there for this kind of construct in different settings than BASH? I would not think it is commonly needed, but it *might* be useful, or even somewhat entertaining!

Comment: I don't have it at my fingertips, but there's an example in the book Exploring Expect that programs two computer players playing chess. Sounds quite appropriate for this problem description.

Comment: Yes, it is that kind of thing - rigging two computers against one another. I believe someone tried it with public-trained chat bots, and they began to abuse each other!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about doing this in a single PowerShell pipeline but it is certainly possible to link together two PowerShell sessions to play a game.  This is a very brain dead version of BlackJack that uses named pipes.  It will probably fall over if you breathe on it wrong but I was able to run through several games - playing the dealer.

```
BlackJackDealer.ps1
-------------------
$suits = 'Clubs','Diamonds','Hearts','Spades'
$ranks = 'Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King'

function GetShuffledDeck {
    $deck = 0..3 | Foreach {$suit = $_; 0..12 | Foreach { 
                      $num = if ($_ -eq 0) {11} elseif ($_ -ge 10) {10} else {$_ + 1}
                      [pscustomobject]@{Suit=$suits[$suit];Rank=$ranks[$_];Value=$num}}
                   }
    for($i = $deck.Length - 1; $i -gt 0; --$i) {
        $rndNdx = Get-Random -Maximum ($i+1)
        $temp = $deck[$i]
        $deck[$i] = $deck[$rndNdx]
        $deck[$rndNdx] = $temp
    }
    $deck
}

function GetValueOfHand($hand) {
    $sum = ($hand | Measure-Object Value -Sum).Sum
    if ($sum -gt 21) {
        $sum = ($hand | Foreach {if ($_.Value -eq 11) {1} else {$_.Value}} | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    }
    $sum
}

function IsHandBust($hand) {
    (GetValueOfHand $hand) -gt 21
}

function IsHandBlackJack($hand) {
    if ($hand.Length -ne 2) { return $false }
    (GetValueOfHand $hand) -eq 21
}

function DumpHand($hand) {
    $cards = $hand | Foreach {DumpCard $_}
    $OFS = ", "
    "$cards"
}

function DumpCard($card) {
    "$($card.Rank) of $($card.Suit)"
}

$npipeServer = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream('BlackJack', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut)
try {
    "BlackJack dealer started"
    "Waiting for client connection"
    $npipeServer.WaitForConnection()
    "Connection established"

    $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeServer)
    $pipeWriter = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($npipeServer)
    $pipeWriter.AutoFlush = $true

    $msg = $pipeReader.ReadLine()
    "Receive msg $msg"

    $command,$playerName = $msg -split ' '

    if ($command -eq 'EXIT') { break }

    "Connected to $playerName. Starting new game. "

    $deck = GetShuffledDeck
    $cardNdx = $deck.Length - 1

    $playerHand  = @($deck[$cardNdx--])
    $dealerHand  = @($deck[$cardNdx--])
    $playerHand += $deck[$cardNdx--]
    $dealerHand += $deck[$cardNdx--]

    "Dealer's hand is $(DumpHand $dealerHand)"
    "Player's hand is $(DumpHand $playerHand)"

    if (IsHandBlackJack $playerHand) {
        $pipeWriter.WriteLine("$playerName gets BLACKJACK $(DumpHand $playerHand)")
    }
    elseif (IsHandBlackJack $dealerHand) {
        $pipeWriter.WriteLine("Dealer gets BLACKJACK $(DumpHand $dealerHand)")
    }
    else {
        $pipeWriter.WriteLine("Dealer's cards are: $(DumpHand $dealerHand)")
        $pipeWriter.WriteLine("Your cards are: $(DumpHand $playerHand)")

        $dealerStands = $false
        $playerStands = $false
        while (1) {
            $pipeWriter.WriteLine("YOURTURN")
            $command = $pipeReader.ReadLine()
            switch ($command) {
                'HITME' {}
                'STAND' {$playerStands = $true}
                default {
                    $msg = "Sorry $playerName, didn't recognize command: '$command'"
                    $msg
                    $pipeWriter.WriteLine($msg)
                    continue
                }
            }

            # Player's turn
            if ($playerStands) {
                "$playerName stands with hand $(DumpHand $playerHand)"
            }
            else {
                $newCard = $deck[$cardNdx--]
                "$playerName requests hit, draws $(DumpCard $newCard)"
                $playerHand += $newCard
                if (IsHandBust $playerHand) {
                    "$playerName busts, Dealer wins"
                    $pipeWriter.WriteLine("You bust with hand $(DumpHand $playerHand)")
                    break
                }
                else {   
                    $pipeWriter.WriteLine("You drew a card, updated hand $(DumpHand $playerHand)")
                }
            }

            # Dealer's turn
            if ($dealerStands -or (GetValueOfHand $dealerHand) -ge 17) {
                $dealerStands = $true
                $msg = "DEALER stands with $(DumpHand $dealerHand)"
                $msg
                $pipeWriter.WriteLine($msg)
            }
            else {
                do {
                    $newCard = $deck[$cardNdx--]
                    $dealerHand += $newCard
                    $msg = "Dealer draws $(DumpCard $newCard), updated hand $(DumpHand $dealerHand)"
                    $msg
                    $pipeWriter.WriteLine($msg)

                    $dealerSum = GetValueOfHand $dealerHand
                    if ($dealerSum -gt 21) {
                        $msg = "DEALER busts with $(DumpHand $dealerHand)"
                        $msg
                        $pipeWriter.WriteLine($msg)
                        break;
                    }
                    elseif ($dealerSum -ge 17) {
                        $dealerStands = $true;
                        $msg = "DEALER stands with $(DumpHand $dealerHand)"
                        $msg
                        $pipeWriter.WriteLine($msg)
                    }
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
                } while (!$dealerStands -and $playerStands)
            }

            if ($playerStands -and $dealerStands) {
                $dealerSum = GetValueOfHand $dealerHand
                $playerSum = GetValueOfHand $playerHand
                if ($dealerSum -gt $playerSum) {
                    $msg = "DEALER wins with $(DumpHand $dealerHand)"
                }
                elseif ($playerSum -gt $dealerSum) {
                    $msg = "$playerName wins with $(DumpHand $playerHand)"
                }
                else {
                    $msg = "The game is a push"
                }
                $msg
                $pipeWriter.WriteLine($msg)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    "Instructing client to close connection"
    $pipeWriter.WriteLine("EXITING")
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
finally {
    "Game exiting"
    $npipeServer.Dispose()
}
```

And here's other script:

```
BlackJackPlayer.ps1
-------------------
$npipeClient = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream('.', 'BlackJack', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut)
$pipeReader = $pipeWriter = $null
try {
    $playerName = Read-Host "Enter your name"
    "BlackJack player connecting to dealer"
    $npipeClient.Connect()
    "Connected to dealer"

    $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeClient)
    $pipeWriter = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($npipeClient)
    $pipeWriter.AutoFlush = $true

    $pipeWriter.WriteLine("STARTGAME $playerName")

    while (1) {
        while (($msg = $pipeReader.ReadLine()) -notmatch "EXITING|YOURTURN") {
            $msg
        }
        if ($msg -match 'EXITING') { break }

        $command = Read-Host "Enter HITME or STAND"
        $pipeWriter.WriteLine($command)
        if ($command -eq 'STAND') {
            while (($msg = $pipeReader.ReadLine()) -notmatch "EXITING") {
                $msg
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
finally {
    "Game exiting"
    $npipeClient.Dispose()
}
```